# AngularJS ui.bootstrap.modal templateUrl not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to wire up a ui.bootstrap.modal object to display some data, I decided to create a seperate html file to hold all my markup for the modal. I can see that some modal tries to open because the screen appears gray. However, in the console I can see that I get a 404 error, although not on the file I intended to use for my template.

**EDIT**- I may have solved my problem. At the config level for this module I was adding ui.bootstrap.modal. After changing that to ui.bootstrap everything works fine.

The only problem is my modal is showing up in the top left corner of my screen?

Code to open Modal:

```
function openModal() {
 $uibModal.open({
 templateUrl: '../Pages/Views/Templates/emailListingView.html',
 controller: function ($scope) { }
 });
};
```

My HTML template:

```
<div>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <ul>
        <li>Bruh</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Angular Error:

> Error: $compile:tpload
>   Error Loading Template

The error window:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () https://localhost:44375/uib/template/modal/window.html

Comment: is that the right path?

Comment: Yes very much the correct path.

Comment: My concern is that my solution doesn't even have a /uib/template/modal/window.html file in it?

Comment: You're probably not using the right ui-bootstrap JS file. Make sure to use the one which contains the templates (ending with tpls.js, IIRC). If in doubt, post your index.html file containing the <script> elements.

Comment: Okay that makes sense so I need to use the one with templates on their website when it says download. This is my first time working with Angular UI directives.

Comment: I went and downloaded the one that has templates and replaced the other one in my project. Still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure and use the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` file.  This is what supports using `<script>` templates.